# Sharpe Ratio is not working for the code I have written in order to plot CAL

Tags: r

sharpe <- (vector_pm – 0.005) / vector_psd

above is the code that is not working I downloaded the needed tseries package and I'm currently trying to find the CAL with data but when I enter the above code I get Error: unexpected input in "sharpe <- (vector_pm –" ...... any solution to this?

I expected it to work all packages are downloaded I believe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.